# Shallow copy object leaving out one or more properties in ES6/ES7?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-2016

This is how I've been doing it:

```js
var props = { id: 1, name: 'test', children: [] }

//copy props but leave children out
var newProps = { ...props }
delete newProps.children

console.log(newProps) // { id: 1, name: 'test' }
```

Is there a cleaner, simpler way?

Comment: I don't understand. You haven't write the most important line, where you copy props to newProps. What's "..."?

Comment: @william.taylor.09, not duplicate. He knows how to copy (he just haven't show that line) but he want's to copy all properties except some in a blacklist

Comment: @Gavriel doesn't this line basically shallow copy the properties the new object `var newProps = { ...props }`? Sort of like doing `var newProps = Object.assign({}, props)`

Comment: It gives me error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token". I don't understand, you said: "This is how I've been doing it", I thought you have a working version, and are looking for a nicer way to do it. However I posted one possible way below

Comment: @Gavriel it's a spread operator: http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=a%3D%7B...b%7D

Comment: ah, I missed the babeljs tag, sebaj :)

Comment: @Bergi, it's not a duplicate. The other question is the complementer of this one: there he wants to copy according to a white-list, and here according to a black-list

Comment: @Gavriel: Ah, right, though a whitelist is definitely cleaner.

Comment: I would say more secure, but cleaner depends on many things. If I have 20 properties and I don't want 2 of them, then blacklist will surely be cleaner or more readable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
var props = { id: 1, name: 'test', children: [] }

var {children:_, ...newProps} = props;
console.log(newProps) // { id: 1, name: 'test' }
console.log(_) // [] - as an "empty" placeholder
```

(with the same [rest/spread properties proposal for ES7](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) that you were already using)

Comment: Yeah I think this is the best option - I was doing something similar before. I just wish there was something more explicit...

Comment: I think it's pretty explicit already… If want, you can write an aptly named function `(key, {[key]:_, ...rest}) => rest` and call that.

Comment: `/* eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "varsIgnorePattern": "_"] */` Is useful to get rid of eslint errors when using this technique

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped. But I should agree with @EvanHobbs - I would've expected to have a much more intuitive way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var props = { id: 1, name: 'test', children: [] }

function clone(orig, blacklistedProps) {
    var newProps = {};
    Object.keys(props).forEach(function(key) {
        if (!blacklistedProps || blacklistedProps.indexOf(key) == -1) {
            newProps[key] = props[key];
        }
    });
    return newProps;
}
var newProps = clone(props, ['children']); 
console.log(newProps) // { id: 1, name: 'test' }
var newProps1 = clone(props); 
console.log(newProps1) // { id: 1, name: 'test', children:[] }
```

Comment: Thanks @gavriel. Yeah for that matter I guess I could wrap my logic in a clone function. I was just hoping there was a more concise way.